# Is martingale solution equivalent to weak solution for SDE driven by stable process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Consider the following SDE
$$
d X_t=b(X_t)d t+d L_t,
$$
where $L_t$ is the symmetric $\alpha$-stable process. The corresponding generator is given by
$$
L=\Delta^{\alpha/2}+b\cdot\nabla.
$$
Is the solution for the martingale problem of $L$ equivalent to the weak solution of the above SDE? (For Brownian motion case, it is well known. But for jump Levy noise, I couldn't find any reference books.)

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Certainly. You might consult the papers of Lepeltier-Marchal ( http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_1976__12_1_43_0.pdf ) or Kurtz ( https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/50ea/0ebc39c875be27c553bbd5827e43ebf5f580.pdf ), the still more general Jacod-Memin ( https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0088728.pdf ).